# Seamless use of Microsoft Teams with an OBS source?

Tags: microsoft-teams, obs-studio

For teaching, I would like to use OBS to switch between scenes. On its own it is great, but I would like to share the live with my Teams meeting. Here what I try:

- Use a VirtualCam : the resolution is very bad, nobody can read anything
- Share the OBS Window Preview : Teams doesn't see the OBS Preview Window
- Share a full screen : It does work, but I cannot use that screen anymore...
- Use Microsoft Stream : I have a 50 seconds lag.

Is there a way to properly share the OBS stream to Microsoft Teams?

Answer (score 0):

One way is using NDI, https://ndi.tv/tools/

Install the OBS NDI plugin which lets OBS output a NDI signal, see [https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-ndi-newtek-ndi™-integration-into-obs-studio.528/](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-ndi-newtek-ndi%E2%84%A2-integration-into-obs-studio.528/)

Install an NDI Virtual Input (part of NDI Tools).  Connect the NDI Virtual Input to the NDI stream produced by OBS. The NDI Virtual Input will then appear as a webcam in software like Teams.  The resolution on the virtual input is whatever you set the OBS output to.

Comment: I am not sure this answer the question. The OP would like to share as screen sharing the OBS window not as Webcam.

Comment: That is not how I understood the question.  Perhaps OP can clarify.